# How to send and Receive messages using Facebook Messenger API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

i am using C# library for FB Messenger API here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook-messenger-net-lib/

But i think there is lack of some documentation . i am trying below code to send message but message is not delivering . Token I am using is Page Access Token generated from Graph api explorer tools.

Code I am trying ( Console Application Code )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FacebookMessengerLib;
namespace FmAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessengerAPI obj = new MessengerAPI("EAACEdEose0cBAOSSBMZAZCd2OTZBT95ZBQbdd69B4eRbWcrWFdZAvUOrnk57DrnaHZARh3lIgZBGxzolZAMjQry9fiZCFjFzQEJJElZATgzTIQB3HsTZCyaimLzeetd37LhTG3yhwfGlxE7ojtdnupopsN3s1ZAzSgQPuxSsgf56MqpJPwZDZD");
            obj.SendTextMessageAsync(660746514005471, "Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we send messages and receive responses using messager api

Answer (score 0):

in order to get user's reply you need to make sure you subscribe the app to the page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/setup#subscribe_app

maybe it has something to do with it..

Comment: going to check it

Comment: can we only send message to users that liked the page or used the app